# I'm real java newbie, and tell me about using netbeans

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

I've heard "If you're newbie, don't use IDE like eclipse, netbeans.. Because you'll be a fool if you used this ide.."

I just practice java little... (including classpath, about basics..) and did coding some..

I just started trying GUI, and thought whether using netbeans or not.. (before I just used vim & cmd..)

when newbie, what is proper for me? All implementing gui by manually and learn low-level of swing? Just using Netbeans's designer and don't care about gui code? Just focus on logic??

And about gui, what is your recommendation? swing & applet? start by awt? gtk? Am I doing hurry?

Maybe my english will be not that good(..) and I'll thank for you about your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget AWT, if you need native widgets you can use SWT. However, with SWT you always have to provide native libraries for the correct platform and bit-ness which can be a hassle.

For starters I'd indeed recommend Swing, even though it looks ugly (yes, even with the platform “native” look and feel), but you don't necessarily need the low-level details. Take a look at the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) – they are really good.

Whatever you choose, there is also a very good graphical authoring tool for Eclipse: [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) which generates useful code to work on and, in general, even works with hand-written Swing code. It says it supports SWT too, but I never tried.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

Comment: I'm reading sun's swing tutorial, which uses netbeans for teaching.. Eclipse is similar? :)